# ErrorType: BaseReducer is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

---

Okay so i'm trying to do my first storage in react native. Using redux obviously. But here is my problem as you can see in the title i have this error.
So this is my code. I suppose that there is a mistake in my store.js But i'm not sure at all. So if someone can help me to handle it.

Here is my **Store.Js**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import {rootReducer} from '../Reducers/profilDetailReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
// Middleware: Redux Persist Config
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: [ "profilDetailReducer" ],
  blacklist: [],
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
let persistor = persistStore(store);

export {
  store,
  persistor,
};
```

My **Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  profilDetails: {
    name:"",
    description:"",
    schoolName:""
  }
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState , action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "SAVE_PROFIL_DETAIL": {
      return {
        ...state,
        profilDetails : action.profilDetails
      }
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
export default rootReducer;
```

And my **action**

```
export const saveProfilDetail = (profilDetails) => (
  {
    type:"SAVE_PROFIL_DETAIL",

    profilDetails: {
      name:profilDetails.name,
      description:profilDetails.Desciption,
      school:profilDetails.school
    }
  }
);
```

I add the file where i'm using it:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import {saveProfilDetail} from '../Actions/saveProfilDetail'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'



class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      school:''
  }}

   handleName = (text) => {
      this.setState({ name: text })
   }
   handleDescription = (text) => {
      this.setState({ description: text })
   }
   handleSchool = (text) => {
      this.setState({ school: text })
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Nom"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handleName}/>

            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Desciption"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handleDescription}/>

            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
              placeholder = "Desciption"
              placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
              autoCapitalize = "none"
              onChangeText = {this.handleSchool}/>

            <TouchableOpacity
               style = {styles.submitButton}
               onPress={() => {
                  var profilDetails = {};
                  profilDetails.name = this.state.name;
                  profilDetails.desciption = this.state.desciption;
                  profilDetails.school = this.state.school;
                  this.props.saveProfilDetail(profilDetails)
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("Profil")
                }}>
               <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      )
   }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      paddingTop: 23
   },
   input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },
   submitButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
      padding: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
   },
   submitButtonText:{
      color: 'white'
   }
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return{
saveProfileDetail:(profilDetails) => dispatch(saveProfilDetail(profilDetails))
}}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

Let me know if you need anything else to help me.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your error is produced by the files above? Are you maybe importing a "BaseReducer" function somewhere else? `BaseReducer` does not look like anything coming from redux itself

Comment: I added the file where i use it. As you can see i don't import any **BaseReducer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading carefully through your code I noticed you mixed up default imports with named imports.

In `store.js` you have:
`import {rootReducer} from '../Reducers/profilDetailReducer';`

And in `Reducer` you have:
`export default rootReducer;`

Since you added a DEFAULT import in your file, this is how the reducer should be imported in your store:
`import rootReducer from '../Reducers/profilDetailReducer';`

You can read more about named and default imports [here](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

I created a basic code sandbox with your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-margulis-0zx6v?file=/src/store.js)

Comment: Can i ask one more thing, now i can't use my "saveProfilDetail" which is my action as i do in the Register.Js. Because "saveProfilDetail is not a function "

Comment: You have 2 problems:
1. in Redux you ALWAYS have to account for mapStateToProps, so when you do your `connect` and have no state to pass, you have to pass `null` as the first parameter
2. you have a typo in your `mapDispatchToProps`, you used `saveProfilEDetail` in one place.

You can write your connect in an easier way:
`export default connect(null, { saveProfilDetail })(Register);`

Comment: Take a look at the example ToDo app and how Redux is implemented there: https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo?file=/src/components/AddTodo.js

Comment: I updated the code sandbox with your code as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-margulis-0zx6v?file=/src/App.js

It fails to navigate now, but that's not something I can test in Code Sandbox, you would need to create an Expo Snack for that

Comment: All of you are lovely thanks a lot for your helps guys it's perfect :)

Comment: There's only one me answering here ;)